# Using python writing list of tuples in file

Tags: python, arrays, string, file, tuples

I have a list of tuples like [(1,2),(2,9),(11,3)]. I want to write it in a file and read it again in the same format i.e. it should be in an array of tuples with integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good task for [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), which serializes python objects

```
import pickle

# save the array to file (with pickle)
myarray = [(1,2),(2,9),(11,3)]
pickle.dump(myarray,open('myarray.pkl', 'wb'))

# load the array to file
myarray_loaded = pickle.load(open('myarray.pkl', 'rb'))
print(myarray_loaded)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) and to then write the pickled object to a file that way you can read the file and unpickle it again.  Remember that pickle creates a byte and not a string.

```
import pickle

v = [(1, 2), (2, 9), (11, 3)]

with open(path_to_file, "wb+") as f:
    f.write(pickle.dumps(v))

# Reading it back   
with open(path_to_file, "rb") as f:
    print(pickle.loads(f.read()))

# [(1, 2), (2, 9), (11, 3)]
```